# How do I show an animation while creating user control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, animation

In a WPF 4 app, I have a very big user control full of controls which takes something like 4s to initialize on a fast machine. During this time the application is of course not responsive at all.
Is there a way to show an animation in the main window while this control is initialized?

I understand that I cannot create it on another thread. But is there maybe a way to create it with a lower priority from the Dispatcher so that I could show a spinning wheel or so on the main window which would still spin?

(The only solution I can think of right now would be to break the user control into further pieces and load them only when needed. But this will take a lot of development time to change.)

**Update1**
To be more clear: It is a simple WPF window using tab pages. When a new tab page is opened I'm initializing the user control which holds the controls for this tab page. One of these user controls is so full of controls that it takes 4s until the new tab page will be shown.
So I thought showing a spinning wheel would be better than having a blocked application.

Comment: Can you include at least a section of the offending code to get an idea of which kind of operations it's doing?

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: Well it's just controls. Imagine a user control with 9 data grids, all having at least 12 columns and using heavy skinning. Even when disabling the data loading for testing this user control takes very long to be initialized.

Comment: yeah, that's the kind of stuff WPF isn't very good at.  It's kinda ironic that a plain javascript+CSS+browser UI often loads faster, and with more general styling, than a styled WPF UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are going to have to break this user control up into pieces. What you can do is use a BackgroundWorker to coordinate the 'building' of this user control. Each time the DoWork event is fired, use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to create an add the next control to your UI. This technique is described in the following blog post:

http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2010/12/wp7-add-user-controls-graphics-in-background-thread/

This will allow you to show an animation during loading.

Comment: I just checked the blog post you mentioned and this looks very interesting indeed. Maybe I'll go that route.

Comment: Along with @ColinE's suggestion, take a look at the AdornerLayer as the place to show your loading animation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it indeed works fine. The only problem now is that I don't have any dev time left, but next time I'll remember to design the app this way from the start. It's unfortunate that component initialization takes so much time with WPF.

Comment: Sorry I first wanted to test also the answer of Eamon Nerbonne. I prefer yours finally as it's much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you initialize it on another thread?  I see two scenarios:

1. Initialization is slow for non-WPF reasons that be preloaded/precomputed on another thread before entering the core WPF initialization.
2. WPF itself is consuming 4 seconds of CPU time (though, that's really WTF levels of CPU time...).  If so, you can start another STA thread with it's own message pump that can display an independant UI (e.g: a spinning wheel) until the primary thread is done loading.

You can create "dialogs" which implicitly create a new Dispatcher and run on a background thread, or you can explicitly create your own Dispatcher (=message pump).

I use the following method to do so:

```
public static Dispatcher StartNewDispatcher(ThreadPriority cpuPriority = ThreadPriority.Normal) {
    using (var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(0)) {
        Dispatcher retval = null;
        var winThread = new Thread(() => {
            retval = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            sem.Release();
            Dispatcher.Run();
        }) { IsBackground = true, Priority = cpuPriority };
        winThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        winThread.Start();
        sem.Wait();
        return retval;
    }
}
```

This gives you real multi-threaded UI; but it also means you can't databind or in any other way directly communicate between the two UI's: after all, WPF objects have thread-affinity.

Before you go this route, verify there aren't any slow components you can preload using a profiler: option 1 (preload heavy stuff before WPF init) is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: Your second point implies a new independent (event transparent) window, right ?

Comment: I've updated the question with some more details to be more clear.
Unfortunately the main window needs to communicate with the user control so the two can't run on a separate thread.

Comment: Well, it *usually* implies a second window; but I suppose technically it just needs an off-screen buffer which could be used (e.g.) via an InteropBitmap on a different thread.  I've never done that before; but it's possible.

Comment: @Marc: I'm not suggesting you run the usercontrol on a seperate thread, I'm suggesting you run some "loading..." animation on another thread.  Your main UI would remain blocked, indeed.

Comment: So I checked all the slow parts and improved some areas, but I still have to show a loading dialog. Could you just give me some more details about when and how exactly you are showing the dialog with your code? I'm invoking "StartNewDispatcher()" in the constructor of the main window, then in the "Window_Loaded()" event handler I'd like to close the loading dialog. Do I have to do this using retval.BeginInvoke(...)? And at which moment should the dialog be initialized and shown? Just before sem.Release()? Thanks a lot for your idea and help!

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to move the slow part (loading data? that doesn't belong IN the control) to another thread as you mentioned.

Or use a [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) to lazy load what is needed.

Could you elaborate on the reason for the delay?